# An audio player that tracks and shows listening time

Tags: audio, audio-streaming

I'm looking for an audio player I can embed on a site that tracks "listening-time" i.e. how far into a song someone listened. Almost every audio player shows "playcount", but that's not a super helpful metric if each play stopped at different points in the recording.

Anyone know of an audio player or widget available that can track how far into a track someone got?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello!  Questions simply asking for a link to something else are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  (If you were asking how to track listening time with your own code, that would be a bit different.)  Additionally, it's difficult to answer your question because there isn't enough information.  What platforms are you targeting?  What sort of audio are you playing?  (Live?  Files?)

Comment: Playing back an mp3 file via an embeddable widget on a website.

Answer (score 2):

For any HTML5 media element (such as `<audio>`), there is a `played` property that indicates what times the listener played the media.  For example:

```
const a = document.querySelector('audio');
for (let i=0; i<a.played.length; i++) {
  console.log(a.played.start(i), a.played.end(i))
}
```

If I listened to seconds 0 through 303 and 707 through 808, this would show on the console:

```
0 303
707 808
```

You can find more information about this here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement